# Force Trailing Slash + Remove .html and website keeps loading error

Tags: html, slash, trailing

I am having problem with adding trailing slash end of URL. I have tried many suggestions from overall web but came up with no successful outcome. Hiding .html works fine, however adding slash does not really work. Main issue is that after I apply code below, the slash appears but website or any page gets never loaded. It keeps in loading mode. I would appreciate if someone helps me through.

My code in .htaccess is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /thanks.html

Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.html(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```